# Inductive Sets and Proper Classes

Tags: set-theory

In ZFC, given an inductive set A, such as the set of natural numbers, and an arbitrary set x, is it possible to construct another inductive set B containing x?  If so, it can then easily be shown that the class of all inductive sets is a proper class.  My attempts to construct such an inductive set B, while being careful to prove the existence in ZFC of any new sets introduced, have failed.

Comment: This is receiving negative feedback because you have phrased it as a homework problem (for the prospective answerers) rather than a question involving input from you. You should edit it to include your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: Question has been edited and, I hope, improved.

Comment: The closure of $\emptyset$ and $x$ under the successor function (what else?) is the set you want. Rigorously justifying that set's existence in ZFC will require some thought (e.g. replacement or recursion theorems that depend on replacement must be used since  an inductive set containing $x=\omega$ can't be shown to exist in ZC).

Comment: The question has been edited, and I hope that it is now suitable for reopening, which I request.  Thank you.

Comment: I gave a hint in the comments... thoughts?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen   Thank you for your suggestions.  I have solved the problem.  Beginning with B = {<0,x>}, I extended B for each n to a set containing elements <k,y>, where k and y are successive successors of 0 and x.  The Axiom of Replacement was then used to create a set C containing <0,x> and such that if <k,y> belongs to C, then <s(k),s(y)> belongs to C for each natural number k.  The Axioms of Union and Separation were then used to create a set containing x and closed under the successor function.  The union of this set with omega is then the desired inductive set.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen  I am puzzled.  Would you mind telling me why my edited question is "off-topic"?  Thank you.

Comment: I thought your question had more reopen votes last time I checked. My guess is that although the wording in the edited question is better, it still didn't have enough context about what you'd tried on the problem and where you were stuck to persuade enough people to vote to reopen.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks.